# "Cannot read property 'data' of null" when trying to read react state

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to set a state allDeals and send it to my component Tabs as props.

```
class IndexHeaderHome extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    let citiesRef = db.collection("Live_Deals");
    let query = citiesRef
      .where("liveDiscountActive", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
          let allDeals = [];
          let data = doc.data();

          let discountName = data.liveDiscountName;
          let discountDesc = data.liveDiscountDescription;
          let discountDisp = data.liveDiscountDispensary;
          let discountCat = data.liveDiscountCategory;
          let discountEnd = data.liveDiscountEndDate;

          allDeals.push({
            // pushing the current email to the end of the array
            discountName,
            discountDesc,
            discountCat,
            discountDisp,
            discountEnd,
          });

          console.log("all deaaaals" + allDeals);

          this.setState({ data: allDeals }); // adding all the emails to the state at once
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-header clear-filter" filter-color="blue">
        <div
          className="page-header-image"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: "url(" + require("assets/img/header.jpg") + ")",
          }}
        ></div>
        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />{" "}
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        <Container>
          <div className="content-center brand">
            <h1 className="h1-seo">Get updates on the latest deals!</h1>
            <h3>Save money everyday with our live deal updates!</h3>
          </div>
        </Container>
        <Container>
          <FilterNow />
          {this.state.data.map((value, index) => (
            <Tabs
              DealName={value.discountName}
              DealDesc={value.discountDesc}
              DealDisp={value.discountDisp}
              DealCat={value.discountCat}
              DealEnd={value.discountEnd}
            />
          ))}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default IndexHeaderHome;
```

But the issue is I am getting the error in the post title.

When I log    console.log("all deaaaals" + allDeals);

I get "object object" as the response.

the error itself is referring to this line here

```
 {this.state.data.map((value, index) => (
```

and these all log the value they should

```
  discountName,
            discountDesc,
            discountCat,
            discountDisp,
            discountEnd,
```

if anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong here and can help me out I would appreciate it =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must setState once after the forEach loop, also the array into which you are pushing the data needs to be initialized outside of the for loop. Also since you haven't initialized state in constructor you would get an error as update of setState happens post the initial render

```
class IndexHeaderHome extends Component {
  state = {
     data: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    let citiesRef = db.collection("Live_Deals");
    let query = citiesRef
      .where("liveDiscountActive", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }
        let allDeals = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());

          let data = doc.data();

          let discountName = data.liveDiscountName;
          let discountDesc = data.liveDiscountDescription;
          let discountDisp = data.liveDiscountDispensary;
          let discountCat = data.liveDiscountCategory;
          let discountEnd = data.liveDiscountEndDate;

          allDeals.push({
            // pushing the current email to the end of the array
            discountName,
            discountDesc,
            discountCat,
            discountDisp,
            discountEnd,
           });
        });
        console.log("all deaaaals" + allDeals);

        this.setState({ data: allDeals }); // adding all the emails to the state at once
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-header clear-filter" filter-color="blue">
        <div
          className="page-header-image"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: "url(" + require("assets/img/header.jpg") + ")",
          }}
        ></div>
        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />{" "}
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        <Container>
          <div className="content-center brand">
            <h1 className="h1-seo">Get updates on the latest deals!</h1>
            <h3>Save money everyday with our live deal updates!</h3>
          </div>
        </Container>
        <Container>
          <FilterNow />
          {this.state.data.map((value, index) => (
            <Tabs
              DealName={value.discountName}
              DealDesc={value.discountDesc}
              DealDisp={value.discountDisp}
              DealCat={value.discountCat}
              DealEnd={value.discountEnd}
            />
          ))}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default IndexHeaderHome;
```

Comment: I put the allDeals array outside of the forEach loop, in your post this.setState looks like its in the same position I have it, should it be somewhere else? I am getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: no this.setState needs to be outside of the forEach loop

Comment: It is outside of the forEach loop.

Comment: Updated the answer, there was another problem related to state initialization